# How can I write the following mathematical formula with arrows?

Tags: symbols, arrows

How can I wrote this unseen (for me) arrows in LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: From `amssymb` package: `\circlearrowright` and `\curvearrowright`

Comment: Yes, thanks to both

Comment: Just only as example (**minimal working example = MWE**) to built the same image of the newbie user to the LaTeX has attached into your question. I agree totally with the user Sigur that have chosen the exact symbols of your image into the `amssymb` package.  `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath,amssymb}
    \usepackage[scr=rsfso]{mathalfa}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
         L(\mathbf{M})=q{\scriptstyle \curvearrowright} H(\mathscr{Q})=\sum^{m}_{i=1}p^{i}_{\circlearrowright}H(\mathscr{P}^{i})
    \end{equation}
    \end{document}`